# Removing false positives from emacs compilation buffer

Tags: emacs, compilation, elisp

In some of the projects I work on, the compilation output have some lines that are not errors but that confuse Emacs since they are similar.

Those false positives are very inconvenient when I use `next-error`, and also distract visually since they are fontified as errors.

I can make a regular expression that filters out those false positives.  What I would like to avoid is to mess with the regexps that are built in into compile.el; they are pretty complex and more importantly they may change in Emacs upgrades.

So what I am looking for is a way to tell compile.el what regexps are false positives (maybe using `compilation-filter-hook`) so they are not flagged as errors.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil
               '(("my-regexp"
                  (0 '(face nil font-lock-face nil
                       compilation-message nil help-echo nil mouse-face nil) t)))
               'append)))
```

This is ugly and brittle, so you probably want to `M-x report-emacs-bug` and ask for a new feature that lets you specify it in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

1. In addition to the automatic filtering that @Stefan mentioned, you can manually filter as needed.
   Buffers such as `*Compilation*` and `*grep*` are just that: *buffers*.  You can thus *edit* them. (For some such buffers you will need to turn off read-only first.)

   And then use `flush-lines` or `keep-lines`.  `next-error` etc. do just what you want: they always work with the edited list of hits.

   (In fact, buffers such as `*grep*` used to be writable by default.)
2. If you use [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) then you can use C-c `  ([`icicle-compilation-search`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Other_Search_Commands#toc8)) in the buffer of compilation hits or grep hits (e.g. `*grep*`) to browse the corresponding code. This has the advantages that it is easy to filter hits dynamically and you can cycle among any subset of them, in various sort orders.

   Using this with Emacs `grep` gives you two levels of regexp searching: 1) the `grep` regexp and 2) your current input regexp (with C-c `). And you can use progressive completion (`S-SPC`) to add additional regexps to match.